# How to get a responsive web site with a border fieldset

Tags: css

Hi I have a problem on my website from mobile.
The desktop view is ok
[image: Desktop view]

[image: Mobile View]

Here's a stack snippet of the page:

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css);

.campiRicettaPersonale{
  margin-left: 7%;
  margin-right: 7%;
  padding-top: 10%;
  height: 100%;
}
.bordFieldset{
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border: 1px white;
  border-radius: 9px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="campiRicettaPersonale">
          <div class="nomeRicetta current">
            <fieldset class="bordFieldset">
              <h2 class="well titolo">Non perdere tempo crea ora la tua ricetta!<br> Per iniziare specifica un nome</h2>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="form-group" id="nomeRicettaIn">
                    <input name="nomeRicetta" id="nomeRicetta" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome della tua ricetta">
                  </div>
                  <span class="help-block" id="nomeRicettaError"></span>
                </div><!--Fine div col-->
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <select name="tipoPiatto" class="form-group form-control" id="tipoPiatto">
                    <option selected value="Selezionare la tipologia del piatto" >Selezionare la tipologia del piatto</option>
                  </select>
                </div><!--Fine div col-->
              </div>
              <input type="button" name="next" class="btn btn-success next btndx" value="Successivo" />
            </fieldset>
          </div><!--Fine div nomeRicetta step 1-->
          </div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query to control the margin and padding in mobile:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .campiRicettaPersonale {
    margin: 5px;
  }
  .bordFieldset {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
  }
}
```

To read more about this, check out this article (5 mins of reading): https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

```css
.campiRicettaPersonale {
  margin-left: 7%;
  margin-right: 7%;
  padding-top: 10%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bordFieldset {
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border: 1px white;
  border-radius: 9px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .campiRicettaPersonale {
    margin: 5px;
  }
  .bordFieldset {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="campiRicettaPersonale">
  <div class="nomeRicetta current">
    <fieldset class="bordFieldset">
      <h2 class="well titolo">Non perdere tempo crea ora la tua ricetta!<br> Per iniziare specifica un nome</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="form-group" id="nomeRicettaIn">
            <input name="nomeRicetta" id="nomeRicetta" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome della tua ricetta">
          </div>
          <span class="help-block" id="nomeRicettaError"></span>
        </div>
        <!--Fine div col-->
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <select name="tipoPiatto" class="form-group form-control" id="tipoPiatto">
            <option selected value="Selezionare la tipologia del piatto">Selezionare la tipologia del piatto</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <!--Fine div col-->
      </div>
      <input type="button" name="next" class="btn btn-success next btndx" value="Successivo" />
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <!--Fine div nomeRicetta step 1-->
</div>
```